# Error using NSErrorPointer to parse .csv

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, csv

Continually getting this error when trying to pass an NSErrorPointer to a parser function as a parameter.

[image]

The function definition is:

```
func parseCSV (contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding, error: NSErrorPointer) -> [(id:String, name:String, age: String)]? {}
```

Comment: you need to pass `error`

Comment: So let error = NSErrorPointer()
then 
print(parseCSV (contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding, error: error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the definition of a function versus calling a function. When defining a func, you specify a name and type, whereas calling a func you specify the same name and a value or variable. When you are calling the func you are passing NSErrorPointer, which is a type. The compiler is trying to convert this to a value of the correct type, which it cannot do. You need to define a variable of the right type, and pass that. For example:

```
 var myError: NSError? = nil
 print(parseCSV(url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &myError))
```